# Count how many times a value appears in a list of arrays in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I have a list of arrays in Excel. They are all numeric values and all reside within column G on my spreadsheet.

```
Row 1 {10,11,12}
Row 2 {10,11,12}
Row 3 {11,12,14}
```

I need to be able to count how many times each number appears in all of the range of arrays.
So in my example above, 10 appears twice, 11 three times, 12 three times, 13 zero times & 14 once.

COUNTIFS doesn't seem to like arrays, MATCH only seems to work if I put the array formula in rather than referencing the cell with the result of the array formula in.

Could someone please offer me any pointers.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by an '*array*' here? Does cell G1 contain the *formula* `={10,11,12}`? Or the *string* `{10,11,12}`?

Comment: Are they stored as text like `{10,11,12}` or `10,11,12`?

Comment: the cell contains the formula =ROW(INDIRECT(F6 & ":" & G6-1)), which when pressing F9 shows the value ={10;11;12}

Comment: What do you have in `F6` and `G6`?

Comment: @David Do you have Office 365? Does the formula you posted, i.e. `ROW(INDIRECT(F6 & ":" & G6-1))` automatically spill into a range of 3 cells? Or does it only return a single value until you highlight it and press F9 within the formula bar?

Comment: @JosWoolley I have 365. It returns a single value until I highlight it and press F9 in the formula bar.

Comment: @Harun24hr the values in F6 & G6 are start time & end time respectively for a rota. Start 10 and finish at 13 should cover the hours 10, 11 & 12 (hence the values in the array). I then have another table that has each hour in the day. Each hour will have a number of staff covering that hour, which I will use conditional formatting to show if there are enough staff to cover. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @David That would seem to be only possible if something is preventing the array spilling. Are you sure there are no #SPILL! errors anywhere?

Comment: @JosWoolley If I click on the formula, press F9 and then press enter, the cell changes to a spill error. Otherwise the cell displays the first number in the array (10). Countif finds the 10s ok because it is like it can only see the first value. I might try to manipulate using MATCH and see if that works

Comment: So resolve the #SPILL! errors. They are not to be left unresolved. Your formulas should be spilling more than a single result. Once you've done that, it will be straightforward to achieve what you want.

Comment: @JosWoolley so it's trying to fill the values down to other cells. Is that the only way it can handle it? I don't want it to go into cells. I just want the values contained in a single cell. The cell beneath is a different employee with different start and finish times.

Comment: An array of values cannot be stored in a single cell. The only alternative would be to store that array *in-formula* for further processing. Do you actually need to have the single result of `ROW(INDIRECT(F6 & ":" & G6-1))` returned to a cell, given that it's meaningless? Why not just pass that formula to some other function within a single, larger formula?